# Gulp Is Getting Stuck in Infinite Loop

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have Gulp set up on an express app project, and it does really well watching my JS files and linting those and then injecting them into my layout file and everything. The Gulpfile.js also injects bower dependencies for me using wiredep and other files I've determined using gulp-inject. All of that works as planned.

However, when I add the typescript compiling task, I get stuck in an infinite loop. Is there something in my file I'm missing that could keep this from happening? [Here's the link to the Gulpfile in a gist](https://gist.github.com/pjlamb12/310c78cc3828653d7ad6906c0889b9a8).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with gulp and typescript.
Gulp didn't wait for the typescript compilation task to finish and started watching the js files, and as they were generated, my page was refreshed multiple times.

I managed to solve it by creating and returning a promise instead of a stream.

```
var Q = require('q');

gulp.task('typescript', function() {
    var d = Q.defer();

    var result = tsProject.src(paths.typescript)
        .pipe(ts(tsProject));

    result.js.pipe(gulp.dest('server/public/app/'));

    result
        .on('end', d.resolve)
        .on('error', d.reject);

    return d.promise;
});
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. The same thing happens, it just gets lost in the infinite loop.

Comment: What's this Q referring to?

Comment: [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) is a promise lib for js. I updated the code to include the required lib.